# How to get checked selected values in the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, html-table, checkedlistbox

I have a problem with the checkbox function in the table. I need to follow the check is true, then the selected company value will be alert.

For example for my coding in the below picture, I want the result to be if I have ticked the first row and the fifth row, then the alert message is shown `Alfreds Futterkiste,Laughing Bacchus Winecellars`

[image: output1]

Below is my sample coding, hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

```js
function show_value() {
  var checkbox_state = []
  var company_name = []
  //use each loop
  $("[name=checkbox_val]").each(function() {
    checkbox_state.push($(this).is(":checked"))
    company_name.push($(this).closest("tr").find("[name=company_name]").val()) //push value in array

  })
  var check_value = checkbox_state.toString();
  
  if(check_value == true){
       alert (company_name.toString());
  }
  

}
```

```html
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="Alfreds Futterkiste" /></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="Centro comercial Moctezuma" /></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="Ernst Handel" /></td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="company_name" name="company_name" value="Island Trading" /></td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="Laughing Bacchus Winecellars" /></td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="updateBtn_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="show_value()">Show selected company value</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can short it down to this:

```
function show_value() {
  var checkbox_state = []
  var company_name = []
  $("[name=checkbox_val]:checked").each(function() {
    company_name.push($(this).closest("tr").find("[name=company_name]").val()) //push value in array
  })
  console.log(company_name.toString());
}
```

One problem was this line `if(check_value == true){` because `check_value` would look like `true,false,false,false,true`so it would never be true.

**Demo**

```js
function show_value() {
  var checkbox_state = []
  var company_name = []
  $("[name=checkbox_val]:checked").each(function() {
    company_name.push($(this).closest("tr").find("[name=company_name]").val()) //push value in array
  })
  console.log(company_name.toString());
}
```

```html
<style>
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="Alfreds Futterkiste" /></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="Centro comercial Moctezuma" /></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="Ernst Handel" /></td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="company_name" name="company_name" value="Island Trading" /></td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="Laughing Bacchus Winecellars" /></td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="updateBtn_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="show_value()">Show selected company value</button>
```